# Saving a telephone number to Simple Schema / Collection2

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I'm using autoform with simple schema and collection2. In my form I collect a phone number. Phone numbers where I live start with a 0. When it saves to the database the 0 is removed. How can I stop this from happening?

```
phone: {
  type: Number,
  optional: true,
  autoform: {
    afFieldInput: {
      type: "tel"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numbers are stored without a leading-zero by definition - 0123 is not a valid number.  You either need to add the leading zeroes when you get data out, or store the value as a string.

Comment: great. That works. How do I stop them from putting in letters?

Answer (score 1):

Save it as a string instead `type: String` or format it with a leading zero whenever you display it on screen. The latter is harder if you are also storing numbers from other locales and you don't know what format they are using.

Answer (score 1):

use a string and add a regex validator on it

```
phone: {
  type: String,
  regEx: /^0{1}\d{10}$/, // or something like this
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the help. FYI to those who might have a similar problem, see the code below. @corvid suggested using regEx and a quick google showed a solution for Australian numbers. It seems to work well. Thanks again everyone!

[Link](http://ilikekillnerds.com/2014/08/regular-expression-for-validating-australian-phone-numbers-including-landline-and-mobile/) for the regEx soltuion

```
phone: {
        type: String,
        regEx: /^\({0,1}((0|\+61)(2|4|3|7|8)){0,1}\){0,1}(\ |-){0,1}[0-9]{2}(\ |-){0,1}[0-9]{2}(\ |-){0,1}[0-9]{1}(\ |-){0,1}[0-9]{3}$/,
        optional: true,
        autoform: {
            afFieldInput: {
            type: "tel"
            }
        }
    },
```